# Graphics driver for Intel 3150?

Tags: drivers, intel

Hello everyone can anyone give me a link to the Ubuntu driver of graphics card designed for Intel 3150?
And is there software which provides a substitute Ubuntu Store Windus content of the file download idm
If so what the name of the software?

Comment: It seems you have two completely separate questions. I suggest you to extract the second one (about Ubuntu Store Windus content, whatever that is) and ask it separately

Answer (score 3):

I believe Intel graphics drivers shipped with Ubuntu include support for Intel GMA 3150 - the support has been included in early 2010 or so. So there's no need to download anything from anywhere.

Comment: If that is not doing the job .... I registered administrator ID that he was not certain but uses graphic sense (?) But I have a laptop
  Sample of asus n2015 and has also nvidia video card built-Ion 2 so maybe if I install the driver of the Ion 2 is a function better
  Where you download the driver that Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

I don't fully understand your question - but you should be fine if you are running the latest version of Ubuntu (intel drivers are included by default).

Answer (score 1):

Type

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

in the terminal and then check system info and youtube (to test 720p) everything will be hunky doory.

If you run `glxinfo` in terminal you should see you have direct rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can get intel graphics from their [open source site](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads)

Once you have run the software it is advised you use synaptics or apt-get for updates.

Answer (score -3):

Try this: http://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&ProductFamily=Graphics&ProductLine=Netbook+and+Tablet+Graphics&ProductProduct=Intel%c2%ae+Graphics+Media+Accelerator+3150+%28Intel%c2%ae+GMA+3150%29

I hope its what you are looking for.

Comment: No! I have no knowledge of content and it did not lead me to any link to another page only * I use the translation of
Google that my English is very basic and I had quite so please sent me straight to the link if you can

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.