# (Lubuntu 18.04.1) Intel GMA3150 drivers

Tags: lubuntu, display, intel, gpu-driver, additional-drivers

I can't install the drivers, they don't appear in additional drivers and the intel graphics update tools for linux don't work in lubuntu. how can i get the drivers?
I have a Acer Aspire one D255E with Atom n450.

[Display info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8RHw.png)
[Additional drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpUs1.png)
[Intel Software](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiq7m.png)

Comment: Did you look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/72605/graphics-driver-for-intel-3150